# How to send email using Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle11g

I am creating auto risk assessment. 
if the risk found the email will be send to concern director. and this work all the time even in week off. 
i have created the procedure for calculating the risk and it is working. but how to let it send email to specific email automatically  for example. xxx@gmail.com. I found one producer but it shows and error: 
Network access denied by access control list (ACL)
here is the procedure:

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE     SEND_MAIL (
msg_to varchar2 , 
msg_subject varchar2 ,
msg_text varchar2  )
IS
c utl_smtp.connection;
rc integer; 
msg_from varchar2(50) := 'smsnotfication@gmail.com'; 
mailhost VARCHAR2(30) := '192.168.10.13'; --  technova local database host 

BEGIN
c := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost,465); -- SMTP on port 25 
utl_smtp.helo(c, mailhost);
utl_smtp.mail(c, msg_from);
utl_smtp.rcpt(c, msg_to);

utl_smtp.data(c,'From: Oracle Database' || utl_tcp.crlf ||
'To: ' || msg_to || utl_tcp.crlf ||
'Subject: ' || msg_subject || 
utl_tcp.crlf || msg_text);
utl_smtp.quit(c);

EXCEPTION
WHEN UTL_SMTP.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
dbms_output.put_line(' Invalid Operation in Mail attempt 
using UTL_SMTP.');
WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR THEN
dbms_output.put_line(' Temporary e-mail issue - try again'); 
WHEN UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
dbms_output.put_line(' Permanent Error Encountered.'); 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't create ACL, did you? If not, here's an excerpt from my script - have a look.

Pay attention to HOST while assigning ACL - this *might* need to be the IP address you mentioned.

I never tried to do what you're doing, but - hopefully - it'll help.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_network_acls;

-- Drop ACL ====================================================================

BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.drop_acl (acl => 'myacl.xml');
END;

-- Create ACL ==================================================================

BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (acl           => 'myacl.xml',
                                      description   => 'SMTP, MAIL, HTTP Access',
                                      principal     => 'SCOTT',
                                      is_grant      => TRUE,
                                      privilege     => 'connect',
                                      start_date    => NULL,
                                      end_date      => NULL);
END;

-- Assign ACL ==================================================================

BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (acl          => 'myacl.xml',
                                      HOST         => '*',     --> 192.168.10.13 ?
                                      lower_port   => NULL,
                                      upper_port   => NULL);
END;

-- Add privilege ===============================================================

BEGIN
   -- SCOTT
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.add_privilege (acl          => 'myacl.xml',
                                         principal    => 'SCOTT',
                                         is_grant     => TRUE,
                                         privilege    => 'connect',
                                         start_date   => NULL,
                                         end_date     => NULL);

   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.add_privilege (acl          => 'myacl.xml',
                                         principal    => 'SCOTT',
                                         is_grant     => TRUE,
                                         privilege    => 'resolve',
                                         start_date   => NULL,
                                         end_date     => NULL);
END;
/
COMMIT;
```